# Book about suppressing First Contact? Character "Polly Ling"?

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, first-contact

This paperback was probably from ca. 1970. The well-off don't want their apple-cart upset by alien tech. Hero saves "Polly Ling" from an alien monster, which turns out to be her husband- she's an alien.

Comment: Yes, this is certainly *it*! At last! I apologize for the incorrect name, but considering Apollo was still a going concern when I read it... Do I need to delete all this, or leave it for the next searcher?

Comment: No need to delete it at all. You can accept Martin's answer: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in).

Comment: I've changed it back to Polly Ling because there's no real need to update it after identified. Also it will help people who also get the name wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Bright New Universe*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?22294) by Jack Williamson.

I was looking for this book too and someone identified it yesterday here [Seeking title / author of a story about alien first contact with Earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/196519/seeking-title-author-of-a-story-about-alien-first-contact-with-earth). The character is actually called Polly Ming not Polly Ling.