# Seeking title / author of a story about alien first contact with Earth

Tags: story-identification, novella

As title, seeking the title of a story I read in the mid 1970s. I'm fairly sure it was a novella in an anthology.

Plot details I can remember - I think main character's family name was Monk.

His father had apparently been killed when the space station he was aboard crashed on the Moon - it later transpires that the station was deliberately crashed to conceal contact with an alien starship, and his father was still alive.
The crew of the starship included various races - one appeared to be a beautiful human woman, while another ( the engineer ) looked like a giant squid. 
After the main character's father died of cancer, the engineer also turned out to be a microbiologist and was able to cure the cancer and bring him back to life.
Other things include a vehicle which was able to go out-of-phase with normal matter and travel through solid objects like the earth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bright New Universe](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?22294) by Jack Williamson

> "Think what it would mean! To prove we aren't alone! To find other
> races - older and wiser than we are! Out on the moon, I hope to find
> an answer. If we do pick up a signal from space, it will be the great
> turning point in human history. It will give our lives a meaning."
>
> Yet to make his words good, Adam Cave had to break with his family and
> society, and put himself against his own world. But once out there on
> the far side of the moon, where an isolated band kept pushing Earth's
> call letters into the void, the picture changed startlingly,
> shockingly. For Cave learned the truth that had been held back from a
> placid world for so long...

Searching inside the [google book](https://books.google.com/books?id=sOU6VNJdonAC&q=monk#v=snippet&q=monk&f=false), there are Monks - possibly his adopted father's name.

[Amazon review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1ED6004YKDE5H/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00005XAEN) mention Adam discovering that his father and his co-pilot making contact with an alien species (a fact that was covered up) and the possibility of his father being alive.

Comment: That's it ! As soon as I looked at the google link and saw mention of a golden egg and the name Polly Ming I knew it was the right one. many thanks ! Ordered a copy off ebay for £3.49 :)